# How can I get Sinatra to generate testrunner-friendly error pages?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack-test

I'm testing a Sinatra app with several of the usual suspects (`rspec`, `rack/test`). From time to time during development, an error within the application will cause Sinatra to generate an error response page. This page is a gorgeous bit of HTML and would be quite nice to use if I was interacting with it in the browser, however, in the text-based testrunner world, it's actually rather difficult to read.

Is there a good way to configure Sinatra such that it will give me these errors in plain text when I run it in a unit/integration-testing environment?